# how to auto hide keyboard after entering a maximum length of text in editText in android?

Tags: android, textfield, textwatcher

Am new to android 
In a app am using editText its maximun text length is 2
Here my question 
After entering two characters in editText (i.e) when editText reaching the maximum text length it shuold automatically hide the soft keyboard 
Can any one say how to do that and is it possible?
I got some answers in stack overflow like this

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = 
        (InputMethodManager) context.
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
        this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

IS it enough ? or i want to do any extra things in coding ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this one in onTextChanged()

```
   {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: After entering 2 text in editText keyboard will hide automatically?

Comment: No, you need to put a listener on textchanged on the EditText, and on each change check the number of characters of the EditText. If that number is > than 2 than hide the keyboard using the above mehtod.

Comment: Can you say please how to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of hiding the keyboard in your application when he reached 2 characters ?
if you want the EditText to be maximum 2 characters, you can do it like this :
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2); //Filter to 2 characters
myEditText .setFilters(filters);

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to listen when the text of edittext being changed. Then you may hide the keyboard when text reached to a specific length.You may use Textwatcher like this.

```
     // replace R.id.editText1 with your edittext id
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final int maxTextLength = 2;//max length of your text

    InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxTextLength);
    myEditText.setFilters(filterArray);

    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){


   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence txtWatcherStr, int start, int before, int count){
       if(count==maxTextLength ){
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: TextWatcher watch the text being changed. When text length reaches to max length, I simply dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work.The above code is enough or else want to write any other